# How to integrate a part of a sphere limited by a rectangle?

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-coordinates

I have a function which depends on the solid angle $\frac{df}{d \Omega} = \frac{df}{d\phi d\theta} $. I want to integrate it over a part of the sphere limited by a rectangle. How should I set the limits of the integral given the position and size of the rectangle?

Lets say that the center of mass of the rectangle is at $(r = \text{dist}, \phi = 0, \theta = 90^ \circ)$ and it is $a$ by $b$ large.

My rectangle is perpendicular to the $XY$ plane, but isn't perpendicular to the $XZ$ not the $YZ$ plane.

Is the Cartesian system with a center in my rectangle a better system for the integral?

Edit: Here is a sketch of my countour. If you know any program which I should use to make a better drawing, I'll be happy to redo it. The corners of the rectangle touch the sphere, the rest of the rectangle is inside. I want to integrate over the surface confined by the graphical projection of the rectangle on the sphere.
[image]

Comment: please verify that $\frac{df}{d \Omega} = \frac{df}{d\phi} f(\theta)$ is what you want there, I when I changed it to latex it was not fully clear what do you mean there...

Comment: I verified that. Thank you.

Comment: No, my rectangle is a normal rectangle with two pairs of parallel sides.

Answer (score 0):

Not Cartesian, the spherical coordinates are the natural and best choice.

It makes *no sense* to refer to large flat rectangles on a sphere.

If the width and breadth are in terms of spherical coordinate symbols we can refer to the limits  as

$$ (\phi_1,\theta_1 ),(\phi_2,\theta_2)   $$

and proceed to evaluate it. There is *no need* further to transform or render it into Cartesian coordinates.

EDIT1:

The limits are independent constants, whether in rectangular system or a spherical system.

However if you are referring to a great circle for instance which is not along parameter lines, $ \phi = f(\theta)$  or $ F(\phi,\theta)=0  $ should be known *a priori.*

Even in the plane if you wanted to evaluate the triangle area between lines $ x=-y,x=0,y=0,$ the contour relation should be known. It is no different here.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me calculate the limits for my integral?

Comment: Are $\theta$ and $\phi$ independent variables for such rectangle?

Comment: What is preserved in your rectangle and spherical patch?  Someone may consider downvote/delete if you are not clear .

Comment: What do you mean by ""what is preserved? Regarding your answer: I am asking if the width and breadth  of the rectangle are limited by $\phi_1$,$\theta_1$),($\phi_2$,$\theta_2$) or maybe these variables are somehow correlated. And what is not clear in my question?

Comment: Can you show a sketch of the contour?

Comment: I am working on a contour. Why must the limits be independent constants? If I wanted to calculate the area of a triangle, the limits in x and y would be correlated.

Comment: :) What is a constant at start is  chosen in design later conveniently. If area A of triangle between 4 geodesics is derived as some $ A= sin ...\phi_1 ... cos.. \theta_1 $ formula, you can adjust the constants as needed.

Comment: Which constant do you mean? The area A isn't a triangle, sice it is between four points. Why would I adjust any constants?